# Check if a string in an array has white space character in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

I am trying to type a text in a conteneditable div and when I loop through them the for loop as an array and check if there are any white space characters (i.e `abc  de` i.e space between the two words it does not recognize them as empty string ). Please see below code.

**Script:**

```
function htmltoBBcode() {
    $("#hidden").html($('#textEditor').html());
    $("#hidden").html($('#textEditor').html()); 
    var arr=$("#hidden").text();
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]=='')
        {
             console.log("i is true"+arr[i]);
        }
        else{
            console.log("i is false"+arr[i]);
        }
    } 
}
```

In the above code, I am taking the text from the contenteditable div and looping through them, if the `arr[i]==''` it should `return true` in the `console.log` but it keeps returning false always, even though it is an empty string(white space).

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/1u84b12h/2/)**

Comment: A space isn't an empty string.Quite unclear what you are expecting. Maybe `arr[i]==' '` ???

Comment: @A.Wolff: when i get the text `abc de` and display it character by character in an array . what will the space be stored as?. I tried getting the typeof arr[i] and it showed the space as string. am i wrong?

Comment: '' == " "; //false always. An empty string cannot be equal to a space character.

Comment: @Pbk1303 I still don't understand what you want/mean. You want to ignore spaces or what?  For 'empty characters' ( do you mean white space characters???), use a regex: `/\s/.test(arr[i])`

Comment: @A.Wolff: thank you, yes your right i was trying to look for white space character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check if a string is empty use:

```
if (!arr[i]) {
  // is emtpy
}
```

Take into consideration that the String is not considered empty if it has whitespace in it! If you want to ignore the whitespace:

```
if (!arr[i].trim()) {
    // is empty 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is not an empty carácter un this position. It's a space carácter. You can check if there space characters by using thisfunction.

```
function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
  return /\s/g.test(s);
}


if(hasWhiteSpace(arr[i]))
             {
              console.log("i is        true"+arr[i]);
             }
```

Answer (score 1):

As A.Wolff pointed out, a space is not an empty string. I also changed `==` to `===` to avoid coercion. Here's a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/hiqiya/edit?html,js,console,output)

js

```
function htmltoBBcode() {
    $("#hidden").html($('#textEditor').html());
    $("#hidden").html($('#textEditor').html()); 
    var arr=$("#hidden").text();
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]===" ")
        {
             console.log("i is true: "+arr[i]);
        }
        else{
            console.log("i is false: "+arr[i]);
        }
    } 
}
```